# Replace text keeping numbers - javascript

Tags: javascript

**BACKGROUND**

I'm handling xml as string for my react-native app. Source text files are stored on the web server as xml format. 
By the way there was some difficulty if I used the parsed xml string itself.

```
<p><verse-number>1</verse-number> verse1 contents <verse-number>2</verse-number> verse 2 contents <verse-number>3 ...  </p>
```

When I parsed this string to object I got the whole verse contents under "p" tag.

```
p: "verse1 contents verse 2 contents ..."
```

So I added some tags to separate each contents like this

```
xml.replace("<verse-number>", "</verse-content><verse-number>").replace("</verse-number>","</verse-number><verse-content>")
```

After this I got this string

```
<p></verse-content><verse-number>1</verse-number><verse-content> verse1 contents </verse-content><verse-number>2</verse-number><verse-content> verse 2 contents </verse-content><verse-number>3 ...  <verse-content></p>
```

Replace function generates some unnecessary tags like after `<p>` and before `</p>`. Some are after and before  tag.

**WHAT I NEED**

I want to remove those unnecessary `</verse-content>` tags (after `<li[numbers]>`) from the string.

From

```
...
<p></verse-content>...
<li1></verse-content>some string here...
<li2></verse-content>some string again...
<li3></verse-content>another string here ..
<ul></verse-content>...
...
```

To

```
...
<p></verse-content>...
<li1>some string here...
<li2>some string again...
<li3>another string here ..
<ul></verse-content>...
...
```

So somethinglike `string.replace()`.

Comment: Why don't you use an xml parser?

Comment: I'm using xml parser and added some tags using string.replace() function to handle them easily by object but as you can see it generated some unnecessary tags like below (in the [..])
<li1>[</verse-content>]<verse-content><verse-number>1</verse-number>Verse contents here</verse-content>[<verse-content>]</li1>

Comment: Then fix how you parse it instead of hacking a regex to do it

Comment: but how? one sec, let me edit question again with better explanation

Comment: @charlietfl, will you check it once again? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML and regex are not good friends. Use a parser, it is simpler, faster and much more maintainable.

---

But, if you really want to use regex, this is working for your case:

```js
html = `
<p></verse-content>...
<li1></verse-content>some string here...
<li2></verse-content>some string again...
<li3></verse-content>another string here ..
<ul></verse-content>...
`;

console.log( html.replace(/(<li\d+>)<\/verse-content>/g, "$1") );
```

**Explanation:**

```
/                   # regex delimiter
  (<li\d+>)         # group 1, tag liNumber
  </verse-content>  # literally
/g                  # regex delimiter, global flag
```

Comment: I'm using javascript not php

Comment: @Tiffgray34: Then, why do you  give an example with `preg_replace` and don't tag with "javascript" ?

Comment: this questions tagged already "javascript", Your answer already working well.by the way how can I solve this using parser?